# Multiplying integer by rational without intermediate overflow

Tags: c++, c, integer-arithmetic, rational-numbers

I have a struct representing a nonnegative rational number p/q:

```
struct rational {
    uint64_t p;
    uint64_t q; // invariant: always > 0
};
```

I would like to multiply my rational by a uint64 `n` and get an integer result, rounded down. That is, I would like to calculate:

```
uint64_t m = (n * r.p)/r.q;
```

while avoiding intermediate overflow in `n * r.p`. (Of course the final result may overflow, which is acceptable.)

How can I do this? Is there a way to do it without a high-multiply?

(I looked at boost::rational but it does not appear to provide this feature.)

Comment: wouldn't it work with `uint64_t m = (n / r.q) * r.p` ?

Comment: Calculate the rational number `n / r.q`, and reduce it to its lowest form, then multiply that by `r.p`.

Comment: @DanielG, Barmar: Neither of these help if `p == n` and `p < q` but `n * p > q`.

Comment: This problem annoys me, it's so simple in x64 assembly but there's no reasonable way to write it down in C.

Comment: Related: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9670/Scaling-bit-integers

Comment: @BenVoigt just realized that. Thanks for the link

Comment: @harold Most compilers now have the high-multiply intrinsic. But not for the double-width divide.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [peasant multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ancient_Egyptian_multiplication):

```
// requires 0 < c < 2^63
// returns (a * b) / c.
uint64_t multDiv(uint64_t a, uint64_t b, uint64_t c) {
  uint64_t rem = 0;
  uint64_t res = (a / c) * b;
  a = a % c;
  // invariant: a_orig * b_orig = (res * c + rem) + a * b
  // a < c, rem < c.
  while (b != 0) {
    if (b & 1) {
      rem += a;
      if (rem >= c) {
        rem -= c;
        res++;
      }
    }
    b /= 2;
    a *= 2;
    if (a >= c) {
      a -= c;
      res += b;
    }
  }
  return res;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Either 128-bits and you might use [Karatsuba](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karatsuba_algorithm) multiplication there; or you might use the Chinese Remainder Theorem to represent (n * r.p) mod p1 and also mod p2. The second might be slower.